# spark web gui disable

Tags: apache-spark, security

I am running Apache Spark 2.4.4. For some security reasons, I want to disable Spark web UI for master and all workers.

used spark.ui.enabled=false conf in $SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf, but I could still see web UI at default port 8080, 8081 for Spark Workers

Comment: Need more info to understand what is happening. Are using spark shell/submit? are u passing custom prop file?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: nope @EmmanuelF